# Storing and loading variables in different Require.js modules

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Im working on a backbone.js and require.js app. I have an app-constants.js file. It stores a number of static variable but also stores country iso codes:

```
define(function (require) {
    'use strict';


    var AppConstants = {
        SESSION_TIMEOUT_DURATION: 300,

        COUNTRY_ISO_CODES: [],

        getCountryIsoCodes: function () {
            return this.COUNTRY_ISO_CODES;
        },

        setCountryIsoCodes: function (countries) {
            this.COUNTRY_ISO_CODES = countries;
        }
    };
    return AppConstants;
});
```

The country iso codes is dependent on the language of the browser so it's loaded after the app starts. So after the language of browser is got, I then load country codes with:

```
appConstants.setCountryIsoCodes(lookUpDataCountries);
```

If i call getCountryIsoCodes() straight after setCountryIsoCodes(), I see the country codes are set in the appConstants file:

```
console.log('appConstants.getCountryIsoCodes() are ');
console.log(appConstants.getCountryIsoCodes());
```

Output is:

```
appConstants.getCountryIsoCodes() are
["CA", "MX", "GT",
etc etc
```

However, if I load the app-constants in another module, e.g. some model, and print out country codes again, I get an empty array. How do I store the country codes in app-constants.js file and load them into different modules?

Comment: ok, so you load module with consts to model module, but are you sure that `getCountryIsoCodes` have been already called?

Comment: yes im sure. the app-constants modules is loaded later, after user has logged in. i think its something to do with garbage collection

Comment: *"so it's loaded after the app starts"* -  it is loaded into what..?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve it, but how about:

```
define(function (require) {
    'use strict';

    var COUNTRY_ISO_CODES: [];

    var AppConstants = {
        SESSION_TIMEOUT_DURATION: 300,

        getCountryIsoCodes: function () {
            return COUNTRY_ISO_CODES;
        },

        setCountryIsoCodes: function (countries) {
            COUNTRY_ISO_CODES = countries;
        }
    };
    return AppConstants;
});
```

Comment: I feel like either you're calling `getCountryIsoCodes` before setting it, or you're setting it back to `[]` somewhere later on... or the page has been refreshed

Comment: no im not, the model i call app-constants in is used much later on in app lifecycle